# Introducing delay after a certain number of iterations in Karate Scenario outline

Tags: karate

I have Karate scripts for scenario Outline which has more than 100 iterations. I want to introduce a delay of 10 seconds after every 20 iterations.

What is the most effective way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `__num` variable: https://github.com/intuit/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements

and do something like this:

```
* if (__num % 10 == 0) java.lang.Thread.sleep(5000)
```

Comment: @SanjeebKumar sorry I had a typo which you should have figured from the docs. use `__num` not `__row`

Comment: I referred to the documentation and included the code. It still doesn't introduce a delay after specified number of iteration.

Comment: @SanjeebKumar sorry I give up. follow this process please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue